# How can I use Canon Photo Print Pro with 64-bit Photoshop CS5?

Tags: photoshop, printing, macintosh

I have a Canon Pixma Pro 9000, I use the photoshop plugin "Canon Easy Photo Print Pro" on a Mac with Snow Leopard with Photoshop CS4.

I have now changed to a New Mac running Lion and upgraded to Photoshop CS5.5. Installing Canon Easy Photo Print Pro does not add the plugin to photoshop.

I have researched this on the Canon website, both USA and UK and Europe and found that there is no support for CS5 due to it being 64bit rather than 32 bit (not sure why that would make a difference)

I have also seen on the [Australia support site there is a new windows update](http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0200065303.html) however there is nothing available for the Mac.

Is there another plugin or piece of software that I can use to set the printing up to match the profile of this printer, as printing directly from Photoshop is not nearly as good as using Easy Photo Print Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect if you use Finder to select the Photoshop app, then "Get Info" and tick the "Open in 32-bit mode" box in the General section you'll be able to use your plug-in again.  You might have to manually copy it into the PS5 plugins directory.  I don't have the Canon software to try out so I don't know for sure.

Running in 32 bit mode might result in a slight performance reduction, and newer plugins might not work.  I'd recommend enabling it only when you're about to print.

Comment: Legend! (7 more to go...) : )

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link for the update for Mac:

http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0200100902.html

Good luck